# swig python output parameter by reference of char** (char**&)

Tags: python, list, reference, char, swig

I'm struggled with the c++ wrap for python using swig, what makes me stuck is the output parameter by reference of char** (a list of char*).

My c++ is like this:

```
class dict{

    int getKeys(const char **&keys, int &result_length)
}
```

I know that I need to use typemap, and I wrote in swig interface file (.i):

```
    %{
    #include "dict.hpp"
    %}

        %apply int &OUTPUT { int & };


        %typemap(in, numinputs=0) char **& (char **temp) {
          $1 = &temp;
        }

        %typemap(argout) char**& %{
            int ntokens; 
            int itoken;

            for (ntokens = 0; *$1[ntokens] != NULL; ntokens++) { 
            }

            PyObject* temp = NULL;
            temp = $result;
            $result = PyList_New(ntokens);
            for (itoken = 0; itoken < ntokens; itoken++) {
                PyList_Append($result, PyUnicode_FromString( *$1[itoken] )); 
            }

            PyObject* list_temp = NULL;
            list_temp = $result;
            $result = PyList_New(1);

            PyList_SetItem($result, 0, temp);
            PyList_Append($result, list_temp);

            Py_DECREF(temp);
            Py_DECREF(list_temp);
        %}
        %typemap(freearg) char**& %{
            free(*$1);
        %}


    %include "dict.hpp"
```

I have no problem when compile .i file, but when I use it in python, **python.exe has stopped working**

```
 resultCode, keys, keysCount = dict.getkeys()
```

I succeed wrapping the output parameter by reference of char* as:

```
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) char *& (char *temp) {
  $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap(argout) char*&  %{
    PyObject* temp = NULL;
    temp = $result;
    $result = PyList_New(1);
    PyList_SetItem($result, 0, temp);
    PyList_Append($result, PyUnicode_FromString(*$1));
    Py_DECREF(temp);
%}
%typemap(freearg) char*& %{
    free(*$1);
%}
```

But how to wrap the output parameter by reference of char** (list of char*)? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is this line:

```
PyList_Append($result, PyUnicode_FromString( *$1[itoken] ));
```

Should be:

```
PyList_Append($result, PyUnicode_FromString( (*$1)[itoken] ));
```

The `$result` handling looks funny, but I didn't continue to debug.  I think a better solution is to use a multi-argument typemap.  Here's what I came up with to test it (Windows OS):

**dict.hpp**

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

API void getKeys(const char **& keys, int& result_length);
```

**dict.cpp**

```
#define EXPORTS
#include "dict.hpp"

API void getKeys(const char **& keys, int& result_length)
{
    result_length = 5;
    keys = new const char*[result_length];
    keys[0] = "abcd";
    keys[1] = "efgh";
    keys[2] = "ijkl";
    keys[3] = "mnop";
    keys[4] = "qrst";
}
```

**dict.i**

```
%module dict

%{
#include "dict.hpp"
%}

%include <windows.i>

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) (const char**& keys,int& result_length) (char **temp, int len) %{
  $1 = &temp;
  $2 = &len;
%}

%typemap(argout) (const char**& keys,int& result_length) (PyObject* obj) %{
    obj = PyList_New(*$2);
    for (int itoken = 0; itoken < *$2; itoken++) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(obj, itoken, PyUnicode_FromString( (*$1)[itoken] )); 
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,obj);
%}

%typemap(freearg) (const char**& keys,int& result_length) %{
    delete [] *$1;
%}

%include "dict.hpp"
```

Output:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dict
>>> dict.getKeys()
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!!! It works!!! Thank you so much Mark, help a lot!!!

Comment: I want to have two return parameters, const char**& keys,int& result_length Although I could get result_length by len(keys), I prefer get it from the function return. So I add a line in dict.i:
$result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, PyInt_FromLong(*$2));